# Como alterar a ordem do gráfico de barras do ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu estou querendo alterar a ordem das barras para que apareçam na mesma ordem que está no `fill` (de acima para baixo: `a`, `b`, `c`).

```
df3<-data.frame(Locus =rep(c("gene1","gene2"), 3),
            variable = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
           value = c(-2.855996957,
           -2.859492255,
           -1.362416086,
           -5.36910352,
           1.493580871,
           -2.509611265))


ggplot(df3, aes(x = Locus, y = value, fill = variable, 
                order = as.numeric(variable))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow", "red", "blue"))+
  labs(title = NULL,
       x = NULL,
       y = "",
       fill = "Tratamentos")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()
```

Fig. errada:
[image: Fig errada]

Fig. desejada:
[image: Fig correta]

Comment: Pedro , seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Não use saudações ou cumprimentos, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize `position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)` dentro da função `geom_col`. O argumento `reverse = TRUE` vai reverter a ordem das barras.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df3 <-data.frame(Locus =rep(c("gene1","gene2"), 3),
                                variable = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
                                value = c(-2.855996957,
                                                    -2.859492255,
                                                    -1.362416086,
                                                    -5.36910352,
                                                    1.493580871,
                                                    -2.509611265))


ggplot(df3, aes(x = Locus, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE, padding = 0)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow", "red", "blue"))+
    labs(title = NULL,
             x = NULL,
             y = "",
             fill = "Tratamentos")+
    coord_flip()+
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Por padrão, a função `position_dodge2` cria as barras com um espaçamento entre elas. Por isso, coloquei o argumento `padding = 0` para que as barras ficassem coladas umas às outras, como no exemplo fornecido.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus!